# HTML Hover only active in Chrome Inspector

Tags: javascript, html, css, tauri

Basically, my CSS code is working for the top right and top left buttons for close and minimize but won't work for the individual mod menu options, if you run the code below you'll see the buttons working except for the ones in the bottom right panel.

In Chrome dev tools It works when setting the hover state active but that's when it only works, My mouse is not actually hovering the object. I used z-index: 255; and it still wouldn't work.

*This is for a Tauri app but should still work the same as a webpage*

```css
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Background{
    z-index: -5;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

#titleBar{
    background-color: #444;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    float: top;
    z-index: -1;
}
#mainWindow{
    background-color: #555;
    width:62%;
    height: calc(96% - 12px);
    top: 12px;
    margin-left: -12px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
#modsWindow{
    background-color: #555;
    width: 40%;
    height: calc(96% - 12px);
    position: absolute;
    left: 62%;
    top: 12px;
    
    margin-left: 1.5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#titleBar #close{
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

#titleBar #folder{
    float: left !important;
}

#titleBar #title{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;

    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
    text-align: center;

    font-weight: bold;
    user-select: none;
    font-size: 2.1em;
}

#titleBar .button{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: right;

    border: none;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;

    transition: all 0.25s;
}
#titleBar .button:hover{
    background-color: #555;
}


/* Mod Tab */
#modsWindow *{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    color: white;


    text-align: center;
    font-size: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;

    overflow: hidden;

    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: bold;

    background-color: transparent;

    transition: all 0.25s;
    border: none;
}

#modsWindow .ACTIVE{
    color: green !important;
}
#modsWindow .INACTIVE{
    color: red !important;
}

#modsWindow .ACTIVE:hover, #modsWindow .INACTIVE:hover{
    background-color: #222;
    color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  

  <body>
    <div data-tauri-drag-region id="titleBar">
      <!-- Close,Minimize, Title & File Buttons-->
      <button id="close" class="button">X</button>
      <button id="minimize" class="button">-</button>
      <button id="folder" class="button">F</button>
      <div data-tauri-drag-region id="title">DBFZ Mod Manager</div>

      <!-- <div id="title">DBFZ Mod Manager</div> -->
    </div>

    <div id="Background">
    
    <div id="mainWindow">
      
    </div>
    
    <div id="modsWindow">
      <button id="modName" class="ACTIVE">MODNAME [ACTIVE]</button>
      <button id="modName" class="INACTIVE">MODNAME [INACTIVE]</button>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css when you want to hover a child, parent z-index should not be negative

Your problem is here :

```
#Background{
    z-index: -5;
}
```

change it to

```
#Background{
    z-index: 1;
}
```